# Overlapping text in matplotlib chart. Used Adjust text package they gave decent results but lines connecting text and point are intersecting

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

i am creating a scatter plot with series of points, these points are clustered in some regions, so text associated to the points are overlapping. I tried using adjust text package, it kind of solved the problem, but some lines are intersecting, which i don't want to happen. I am trying to tune parameters given to adjust text, so far no success.

I have attached my script and chart o/p below. PS: i have disguised the text of each points

Any thoughts or suggestions

```
from adjustText import adjust_text

adjust_text(texts,expand_objects=(10,10),force_points=(25,25),lim=1000,force_text= 
(50,50),only_move={'points':'xy','texts':'xy'},arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="- 
>",color="r",lw=0.5))
```

[image: Here is the chart]

Comment: You need to greatly reduce the forces to get better results. Typical values for forces are more like 0.1. Without your data can't really test it though.